# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.WindowInsets.isConsumed()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, nullpointerexception

I'm working with unity3d by using UnityActivity. I have a MainActivity where starts UnityActivity by

```
    Intent unity = new Intent(this, UnityActivity.class);
    startActivity(unity);
```

UnityActivity and MainActivity are both

```
launchMode="singleTask"
```

After working with unity, I call the code below

```
UnityActivity.this.finish();
```

And I get the error:

```
    D/MainActivity(25562): onStart
    D/MainActivity(25562): onResume
    D/AndroidRuntime(25562): Shutting down VM
    E/AndroidRuntime(25562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    E/AndroidRuntime(25562): Process: ru.mdinc.mdinc, PID: 25562
    E/AndroidRuntime(25562): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.WindowInsets.isConsumed()' on a null object reference
    E/AndroidRuntime(25562):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7077)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25562):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl.java:1670)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25562):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2083)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25562):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1468)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25562):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7208)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25562):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1004)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25562):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:816)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25562):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:751)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25562):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:990)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25562):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25562):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25562):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25562):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25562):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25562):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25562):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I did not override any methods of WindowInsets, so don't put links like "you forget initialize variable before using it"

I expect that UnityActivity will be closed and MainActivity restart with previous state.

Before adding functionality with Vuforia that code was working fine.

EDIT: found that error occurs [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#7105)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that for me. I'm using `mUnityPlayer.pause()` BEFORE activities `onPause()`.

For example, I need to handle Service message and close UnityActivity, so I do that:

```
switch(message) {
    ...
    case "stop-unity": 
       mUnityPlayerPause(); //Pause the unity before activities onPause()
       isFinish = true; //field of UnityActivity class
       UnityActivity.this.finish(); //Stop activity
       break;
}
```

And now inside `onPause()` method need to check is that `isPause` action:

```
@Override 
void onPause() {
    if (!isFinish) mUnityPlayer.pause(); //Pause unity only when it's system call 
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I catch this crash not embeding Unity Activity to Android but a usual Unity app, with `Application.Quit();` called, there might be chance that this crash occur.

After some try, I found that might be a Unity bug. It's everything fine with LTS version of Unity(Unity2018.4 LTS) build, While Unity 2018.3.1f1 (64-bit) versioin build cause this crash.

Try to use LTS Unity version! Hope to help Anyone googles here.